# Break loop from an if else statement

Tags: jquery, function, break, if-statement

I'm new to jQuery, let me know if I'm doing it right. So here's my code. I nested this function in another function. I want it to execute (pretty much just toggling images) until a count of 3 then continue to execute the rest of the parent function.

```
//parent function part 1
    $(function flip(){
        var count=1
        if (count==3) {
            return var count=1;
        } else {
            $('#i1').toggle(2);
            $('#i1').toggle(2);
            var count=count+1
        });
//parent function part 2
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? `return var count=1;` looks fishy

Comment: haha I have no idea but I'll delete that. new to jQuery

Comment: Where is the loop 0.o?

Answer (score 0):

declare `var count=1` out of the function flip
this is because each time the function is called count becomes one and the if part will be never executed

Answer (score 0):

you say that you want to execute until a count of 3, you can easily use loop like this :

```
var count = 1
while(count <= 3){
 // your code here 
 $('#i1').toggle(2); // etc ...
 // .....
 count++; 
}
count = 1;
```

about your code there is some problems :

```
//parent function part 1
$(function flip(){
    var count=1
    if (count==3) {
        count=1; // <--- no var here because if you use var you are declaring a new variable, and why you use return ?? if you want juste to reset your count variable we don't need any "return" !
    };
    else {
        $('#i1').toggle(2);
        $('#i1').toggle(2);
        count=count+1  // <--- no var here because if you use var you are declaring a new variable
    } // end of if else statment

 }  //  <---- add this to close your function declaration block
 );
```